# serving text/HTML content to chrome in asp.net shows page text

Tags: html, asp.net, google-chrome

I dynamically generate an html page in an .aspx file like this:

```
Response.Clear()
Response.ClearContent()
Response.ClearHeaders()
Response.Buffer = True
Response.ContentType = "text/HTML"
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline")
Response.OutputStream.Write(FilledBuffer, 0, FilledBuffer.Length)
Response.OutputStream.Flush()
Response.OutputStream.Close()
Response.End()
```

where FilledBuffer (a byte array) is valid html like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>My Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<div>content</div>
</body>
</html>
```

When I view this in IE8+ it renders an as html page, however in Chrome it displays the html as text.  My first thought is the MIME type but text/HTML is correct for html, so I am at a loss.

I must be missing something very simple here...or the internet would not work...

In fiddler the request between a standard aspx page that renders html and the above non-working page are identical, specifically:

```
GET http://localhost:1202/test.aspx HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:1202
Connection: keep-alive
Accept:    text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like     Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.112 Safari/537.36
Referer: http://localhost:1202/Mypage.aspx
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
```

Comment: In fiddler the content is < ! D O C T Y P E   h t m l > < h t m l > < h e a d > < t i t l e > M y   P a g e < / t i t l e > < / h e a d > < b o d y > < d i v > < h 1 > C o n t e n t < / h 1 > < d i v > < / b o d y > < / h t m l > with spaces between each charter which looks like unicode perhaps? I added response.encoding = "utf-8" with no effect.

Comment: You should show the different _response_ headers between working and non-working.

Comment: RESOLVED - file under working too late. I created the byte array from a string with System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(sb.ToString) it should be System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sb.ToString).

Comment: Nice. You'd might as well post your own answer to your question in case someone else runs across this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The byte array used by the response stream was created with unicode encoding, thus the output was indeed unicode.  Interesting that IE does not seem to care about this but Chrome recognized this was not html and simply rendered the page as text. The giveaway unicode double charter width was not displayed by Chrome and inspecting page source showed a perfectly valid looking html file.  It was not until inspection in fiddler that the unicode was detected which lead to the discovery of the incorrect conversion.